# scikit-learn random forest: severe overfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am attempting to apply knn, logistic regression, decision tree, and random forest to predict a binary response variable.

The former three produce seemingly reasonable accuracy rates, but running the random forest algorithm produces an accuracy rate of over 99% (1127/1128 correct).

```
vote_lst = list(range(1, 101))
rf_cv_scores = []
for tree_count in vote_lst:
    maple = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = tree_count, random_state = 1618)
    scores = cross_val_score(maple, x, y, cv = 10, scoring = 'accuracy') # 10-fold CV
    rf_cv_scores.append(scores.mean()) 

# find minimum error's index (i.e. optimal num. of estimators)
rf_MSE = [1 - x for x in rf_cv_scores]
min_error = rf_MSE[0]
for i in range(len(rf_MSE)):
    min_error = min_error
    if rf_MSE[i] < min_error:
        rf_min_index = i
        min_error = rf_MSE[i]
print(rf_min_index + 1) # error minimized w/ 66 estimators
```

I tuned the rf algorithm hyperparameter `n_estimators` using the code above. Then, I fit the model on my data:

```
# fit random forest classifier
forest_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = rf_min_index + 1, random_state = 1618)
forest_classifier.fit(x, y)

# predict test set
y_pred_forest = forest_classifier.predict(x)
```

I'm concerned that some drastic overfitting occurred here: any ideas?

Comment: It may be the case. After tunning the hyperparameters, instead of fitting the best model on the whole dataset, use cross-validation. If you still get a 99% WITH cross validation you can interpret this as a perfect classifier. Try to use KFolds with K = 10

Comment: And even if you use cross validation to pick out the best parameters for each model, the performance on that data set will be a biased estimate of the generalization error, which is unhandy if the goal is model selection. You'll want to look into nested cross-validation here.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm concerned that some drastic overfitting occurred here: any ideas?

You're making predictions on the same dataset you've trained above:

```
y_pred_forest = forest_classifier.predict(x)
```